# python nested for to print out the position and name of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to use a **nested for to print out the position and name of a column in a dataframe**. I do that because the .csv contains 185 columns and find it easier to print out 0 -> columnName.

With this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv', encoding='utf_8', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
[print(e,"->",col) for e,col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

I try to get this output:

```
0 -> colName0 
1 -> colName1 
2 -> colName2 
3 -> colName3 
4 -> colName4
```

However, this is what I get

```
0 -> colName0 
1 -> colName1 
2 -> colName2 
3 -> colName3 
4 -> colName4

[None,
None, 
None, 
None, 
None]
```

If I use a for loop with a print inside the output is how I expected.

```
for (e,col) in enumerate(df.columns):
   print(e,"->",col)
```

I am using:

- Anaconda 5.1.0 build py36_2
- Anaconda-client 1.6.9
- Anaconda-navigator  1.7.0
- Browser: Opera 52.0.2871.99

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a list comprehension to call print. This evaluates to a list of None's (which is the return value for print).

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
[print(e,"->",col) for e,col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

you perform a list comprehension. While you print, you also create a list. Since print function returns None, you end up creating a list of None types. This is what you see at the end.